# Sort lists chronologically within grouping, then stack by grouping (some lists are manually entered, some are form-generated)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a series of lists that will each be accorded a priority ranking (A, B, or C). Each ranking will consist of one manually entered list and at least one form-generated list. I would like to sort each priority group chronologically (ie all manual and generated A lists becoming one sorted A list) and then stack each sorted list by priority in one master list.

Complications:

- I am building this for my boss, and I know for a fact that she will forget to enter the timestamp on the manual lists, so it must be automatically generated. It also cannot be volatile, like the now() function, it must be a static timestamp. (Form-generated lists will have an automatic timestamp).
- the manually entered lists and the master list must all be on the same sheet, or she *will* enter the manual data directly on the master sheet and break the system (I have seen this happen countless times).
- Ideally all the data would be on one sheet, as I have to make ~20 of these in the same workbook and I don't want it to get out of control.
- some of the rows in each list may be blank (aside from the ranking column)

I have a sample sheet with my desired outcome [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18aKbwqIDXVLVzfASkpVKbhvm0bUMHO2O1OrgW4_gzr8/edit#gid=0). In the interest of time I have not filled it in with pretend data, hopefully that is not an issue.

FILTER doesn't seem to stack ranges that are out of order (like on my sheet). Using SORT before QUERY sorts all the entries, not just within each ranking. I can't come up with anything to sort within each ranking first, then stack those ranges out of order. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this formula: it will filter all the range according to if it has or not one of the priority values (in column B, avoiding the titles) and if it has a timestamp

Then all that range is sorted by both columns

```
=SORT(FILTER(A61:F,INDEX(IFNA(MATCH(B61:B,{"A";"B";"C"},0),))>0,A61:A<>""),2,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to work perfectly. I experimented but want to double-check, if I wanted to expand the lists to include an additional column, I could just change the range to A61:G, correct? It seems to work but don't want to break something by accident.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, no problem! You can add as many columns as you need. What's important about FILTER is that it has the same amount of rows OR the same of columns, depending on the direction you're filtering

Comment: Thank you very much! I've put it into my real data and it's working perfectly. You have saved me many hours of manual data entry! Appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The same sheet problem. Master list will grow when manual list will grow so it should be below all manual lists.
2. No timestamp problem. You can try to help your boss, adding conditional formatting. Whenever she puts any data in a row and timestamp columns is empty, you can color it red. For example. If you need timestamp in A5, you should click: Format --> Conditional formatting and then choose custom formula and enter: `=and(join("",C5:F5)<>"",A5="")`and choose red background. Formatting will be removed when she adds anything to A5.
3. Stacking problem. When you have a limited list of types of data, you can stack them using {} notation. For example {A1:B10;C1:D10} stacks 2 tables one on another and you can implement sorting before stacking like: {sort(A1:B10);sort(C1:D10)}

4.Automatic fill of timestamp - is possible only using scripts.

5.When you are afraid that master sheet can be destroyed by your boss, you can protect range from edit using: "Protect sheets and ranges" in Data menu.

My solution for building master is to use query:

```
=query(A61:F,"Select * where B is not null and B != 'Ranking' order by B asc, A desc",0)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with all my concerns. I will add conditional formatting and hopefully that will help somewhat (it's more an impatient personality issue than forgetful). I have tried protecting ranges before but since we use the same account (ie she's also the owner), she only gets a warning and it doesn't seem to do any good. Good tip about using sort inside {} to stack ranges, I will try to remember that.

For the solution, it's very elegant but it doesn't seem to sort chronologically in the first column. Would it be possible to work that in somehow? Thank you for your help!